# Search menu with multiple options

Tags: c#, object-oriented, asp.net-mvc

```
    if(selectedGroup == 0 && model.selectedParameterItem != null)
    {
        foreach (var i in model.selectedParameterItem)
        {
            parameters.Add(db.ParametersMethods.Where(f => f.ID == i).FirstOrDefault());
        }
        methods.AddRange(methodlogicclass.GetMethodFromParameters(parameters));
        ViewBag.methods = convertMethod(method);

        return View(methodModel);
    }

    else if (selectedGroup !=0 && model.selectedParameterItem == null)
    { 
        methods = db.Methods.Where(f => f.MethodGroupID == selectedGroup).ToList();
        ViewBag.methods = convertMethod(methods);

        return View(methodModel);
    }

    else if(selectedGroup != 0 && model.selectedParameterItem != null)
    {
        List<Methods> groupMethods = db.Methods.Where(f => f.MethodID == selectedGroup).ToList();
        foreach (var i in model.selectedParameterItem)
        {
            parameters.Add(db.ParametersMethods.Where(f => f.ID == i).FirstOrDefault());
        }
        List<Methods> parameterMethods = methodlogicclass.GetMethodsFromParameters(parameters);



        foreach(var methods1 in groupMethods)
        {
            foreach(var methods2 in parameterMethods)
            {
                if(methods1.ID == methods2.ID)
                {
                    methods.Add(method2);
                }
            }
        }

        ViewBag.methods = convertMethods(methods);

        return View(methodModel);
    }
```

So I'm trying to create a searchmenu, with multiple options that don't necessarily have to be selected. However, search results obviously have to meet every option selected.

What would be the best way to write code like this, with the least amount of duplication, while keeping into account that model.selectedParameterItem (for instance) can be null and thus can't be used. Right now the code isn't closed for modification at all, which is far from optimal.

WHat would be best practice in a case like this? Check for each element if it is null, then get the results for each of them seperatly, then merge all the results?

Code explained:

1. Search by group => search for methods by group
2. Search by parameter => search for methods by parameters
3. Etc, more will be added
4. When searching for both, only return the methods that meet both group and parameter requirement (and in the future, other requirements).
5. Group can be empty (0), list of parameters can be empty (null).
6. Future added requirements will be able to be empty (null)

Comment: First advice - use English language for naming, just like .NET do. I assume you are using German now. For people who don't speak German your code looks like obfuscated: `foreach (var a in b) { foreach (var c in d) { x.Add(c); }}}`

Comment: What are `parameters`? What is `wvl`? What `GetWerkovormUitBlahBlah` method does?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I edited the code to English. Each method has a number of parameters that are met, GetMethodsFromParameters gets all the methods that meet the required parameters. wvl (now methodlogicclass) is the business class for the method revolving around methods, it is used to give back methods that meet the parameters.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.CodeReview.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: You will need more information to get a true answer.  What is db?  Entity framework?  What is parameters? A list of some class?  What is method object? what is convertToMethods method?

Comment: If you add the context above the code your question will be noticed better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use English language for naming. .NET uses English for naming. You have mix of languages, and code looks like obfuscated for those who don't speak German.
2. Use descriptive names. I don't know German, but `wvl`, `wek1`, `wek2` is definitely not very descriptive.
3. You have mix of presentation-related and data access code. You should split this code.

So, the first part is your controller code. It should look like technical specification when you read it. Let's try to do that

```
var methods = GetMethods(selectedGroupId, model.selectedParameterItem);
var model = ConvertMethodsToModel(methods);
return View(model);
```

Pretty clean. Now lets think about `GetMethods` method. It's purpose is returning some methods depending on what was found in methods group and parameter methods. Btw it can be method of another class (e.g. some service)

```
private IEnumerable<Method> GetMethods(int groupId, IEnumerable<int> parameterIds)
{
   var none = Enumerable.Empty<Method>();
   var groupMethods = (groupId == 0) ? none : GetMethodsByGroup(groupId);
   var parameterMethods = (parameterIds == null) ? none : GetParameterMethods(parametrIds);

   if (!parameterMethods.Any())
       return groupMethods;

   if (!groupMethods.Any())
       return parameterMethods;

   var parameterMethodsFromGroup =
        from pm in parameterMethods
        join gm in groupMethods on pm.Id equals gm.Id
        select pm;

   return parameterMethodsFromGroup;
}
```

And last part - those `GetMethodsByGroup` and `GetParameterMethods` (which could be moved to corresponding repositories):

```
private IEnumerable<Method> GetMethodsByGroup(int groupId)
{
    return db.Methods.Where(m => m.MethodGroupID == groupId).ToList();
}
```

Getting parameter methods:

```
private IEnumerable<Method> GetParameterMethods(IEnumerable<int> parameterIds)
{
    var parameterMethods = db.ParametersMethods.Where(pm => parameterIds.Contains(pm.ID));
    return methodlogicclass.GetMethodFromParameters(parameterMethodss).ToList();
}
```

Comment: The `GetMethodsByGroup` is calling `ToList` internally so I think it's better to return an `IList` so that the user knows he doesn't have to call it agian himself. It's always tempting to do it if a method returns an `IEnumerable` especially that `Any` is used and then agian the result is used in a query. You would get the possible multiple enumerations warning from ReSharper. The same applies to `GetParameterMethods`.

Comment: @t3chb0t well, agree. But I rather go with removing `ToList()` from data access methods. Or returning Collection

Comment: Either way is actually fine but... by removing `ToList` it might happen that the `db` (probably context) is out of scope and already disposed so an exception will occur. But 2 - since we don't know the exact details let's say it's ok to return an IEnumerable ;-]

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to keep your current code, I would probably change the order of the if statements a little bit, and maybe separate some of the conditions out, definitely re order, the odd one out is `model.selectedParameterItem == null && selectedGroup != 0`  I would make that the first statement, like this

```
if (model.selectedParameterItem == null && selectedGroup != 0)
{
    methods = db.Methods.Where(f => f.MethodGroupID == selectedGroup).ToList();
    ViewBag.methods = convertMethod(methods);

    return View(methodModel);
}
else if (model.selectedParameterItem != null && selectedGroup == 0)
{
    foreach (var i in model.selectedParameterItem)
    {
        parameters.Add(db.ParametersMethods.Where(f => f.ID == i).FirstOrDefault());
    }
    methods.AddRange(methodlogicclass.GetMethodFromParameters(parameters));
    ViewBag.methods = convertMethod(method);

    return View(methodModel);       
}
else if (model.selectedParameterItem != null && selectedGroup != 0)
{
    List<Methods> groupMethods = db.Methods.Where(f => f.MethodID == selectedGroup).ToList();
    foreach (var i in model.selectedParameterItem)
    {
        parameters.Add(db.ParametersMethods.Where(f => f.ID == i).FirstOrDefault());
    }
    List<Methods> parameterMethods = methodlogicclass.GetMethodsFromParameters(parameters);

    foreach(var methods1 in groupMethods)
    {
        foreach(var methods2 in parameterMethods)
        {
            if(methods1.ID == methods2.ID)
            {
                methods.Add(method2);
            }
        }
    }

    ViewBag.methods = convertMethods(methods);

    return View(methodModel);       
}
```

and actually I was thinking that you should increase the indentation one level inside of your else if block, because of the conditions... the `selectedGroup` condition is the only thing different, no need to check the `model.selectedParameterItem != null` condition a third time.

```
if (model.selectedParameterItem == null && selectedGroup != 0)
{
    methods = db.Methods.Where(f => f.MethodGroupID == selectedGroup).ToList();
    ViewBag.methods = convertMethod(methods);

    return View(methodModel);
}
else if (model.selectedParameterItem != null) //&& selectedGroup == 0)
{
    if (selectedGroup == 0)
    {
        foreach (var i in model.selectedParameterItem)
        {
            parameters.Add(db.ParametersMethods.Where(f => f.ID == i).FirstOrDefault());
        }
        methods.AddRange(methodlogicclass.GetMethodFromParameters(parameters));
        ViewBag.methods = convertMethod(method);

        return View(methodModel);       
    }
    else if (selectedGroup != 0)
    {
        List<Methods> groupMethods = db.Methods.Where(f => f.MethodID == selectedGroup).ToList();
        foreach (var i in model.selectedParameterItem)
        {
            parameters.Add(db.ParametersMethods.Where(f => f.ID == i).FirstOrDefault());
        }
        List<Methods> parameterMethods = methodlogicclass.GetMethodsFromParameters(parameters);

        foreach(var methods1 in groupMethods)
        {
            foreach(var methods2 in parameterMethods)
            {
                if(methods1.ID == methods2.ID)
                {
                    methods.Add(method2);
                }
            }
        }   
        ViewBag.methods = convertMethods(methods);
        return View(methodModel);       
    }
}
```

I would also suggest using LINQ in the rest of your code, you use it sparingly throughout but not everywhere that you can.  it would make the code a lot cleaner and get rid of nesting the foreach loops as well.

Your code here:

> ```
> foreach (var methods1 in groupMethods)
> {
>   foreach (var methods2 in parameterMethods)
>   {
>       if (methods1.ID == methods2.ID)
>       {
>           methods.Add(method2);
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

would look a lot better like this

```
methods.AddRange(groupMethods.Select(gm => parameterMethods.First(pm => pm.ID == gm.ID)));
```